# Delete all rows with duplicate values in column in Palantir Foundry Countor

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

In a contour analysis with over 2 million rows I need to remove all rows where the 1st column `WORKORDER_ID` is a duplicated STRING value. I have already sorted by modified time so I want to keep the 1st unique instance.

I have tried writing expressions but have not been able to create anything that would run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Contour, how do I filter down to the top N by values in a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015392/in-contour-how-do-i-filter-down-to-the-top-n-by-values-in-a-group)

Comment: TY.  That is essentially what ended up happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will give you row_numbers starting from 1 for each `WORKORDER_ID`. After that you just need to add a filter to only keep the rows where `row_number` is 1.

```
row_number() OVER (
PARTITION BY "WORKORDER_ID"
ORDER BY "modified_time" ASC
)
```

[image: Code in the contour expression board]

Comment: TY!  That got me down from 2 million+ rows to 976.  Exactly what i needed